# What is the right way to validate a client TLS cert using the tls library in Haskell?

Tags: validation, security, haskell, ssl, client-certificates

I have a working Yesod/Warp server. I would like to equip this server with the ability to allow admin users to authenticate themselves using client-side certificates. Additionally, I would like to assign each administrator their own client certificate, so that I can track them individually on the server.

The current version of the server does not use TLS (it is currently deployed behind a TLS termination proxy), so I have created an additional executable target in the cabal file. This new executable replaces `Network.Wai.Handler.Warp.runSettings` from the `warp` package with `Network.Wai.Handler.WarpTLS.runTLS` from the `warp-tls` package.

In the `Network.Wai.Handler.WarpTLS.TLSSettings` I provide to `runTLS`, I set `tlsWantClientCert` to `True` and provide an implementation of `onClientCertificate`. My question is, what do I need to do in `onClientCertificate` to make sure that the client cert is valid? What has already been checked about the client cert (if anything), and what still needs to be checked? Right now, the server cert chain and the client certs are unrelated; does the `tls` library do more if they’re related in some way?

`Network.TLS` has a section labeled “X509 Validation,” but I don’t see anything in that section that performs validation. Looking at the source, it seems that everything in that section comes from the `Data.X509.Validation` module in the `x509-validation` package. That module additionally provides a `validate` function. Is that sufficient? Is there an existing mapping from `Data.X509.Validation.FailedReason` to `Network.TLS.CertificateRejectReason`?

Comment: In addition to describing what you have done, I'd suggest also adding some important bits of code. Also I would try asking just one question at a time. Maybe try splitting this huge post, with at least 5 questions, into separate questions.

Comment: @Ente I disagree. This question explains perfectly what's desired, and there's no relevant code to be posted. It's also a single question on how to accomplish a single goal (validating client certificates) that's just an on/off setting in most programs, so it shouldn't be split up.